# Would a question about analyzing the CRU programs be closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I'm trying to go through the [CRU](http://wikileaks.org/wiki/Climatic_Research_Unit_emails,_data,_models,_1996-2009) leaked programs and do some basic program analysis.  I'm encountering some difficulty due to the fact I don't know Fortran.  I'd like to post a question on StackOverflow offering the link and keeping track of interesting things people find (Community Wiki of course).  For various reasons this seems likely to be closed.  Would this be an acceptable question to ♦Management, and if so, how could I make it less likely to be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is about Fortran, there will be no problem. If its about climatic research, this obviously is not the place - unless maybe questions about algorithms and such.

So make it programming oriented, and you do not even have to c-wikify it.

But where do you see likelihood for closing?

Comment: Lately anything that is remotely open ended seems to get closed.

Comment: Also, just like on /., the left wing croud tends to get emotional about sacred cows and does not care if somethinjg is a legit Fortran Q or not. HERECY! PITCHFORKS!

Comment: FWIW, this doesn't sound remotely open-ended. It sounds extremely open-ended. I would probably vote to close without a second thought, *unless* : 1) you made it CW. 2) you were careful to set strict boundaries as to what was appropriate. 3) those boundaries align reasonably well with those of the site itself (programming-related info *only* : leave CRU discussion to another site). And keep in mind, chances are it would *still* get flagged as offensive if flame-wars broke out...

Answer (score 2):

without an example, it's hard to say.

the best way to know is: post one and find out; make it c-wiki

Comment: Second the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer both Ralph's last question ("But where do you see likelihood for closing?") and the OP's in one.

The main two reasons this might be closed is:

- Some people might feel that it would not be sufficiently "programming related" and in SO spirit. I personally don't think so (and I'm usually pretty strict when voting to close Qs).
- People of a particular ideological bent, for a variety of psychological, moral and other reasons, tend to violently react to anything going against their dogma. Anthropogenic Global Warming is one such sacred cow. So anything which questions it - no matter how logical, rational or meaningful - will be promptly extinguished, scientific method be damned.

As far as Management, Joel is flying an Obama banner on JoS web site, but he generally strikes me as a guy with integrity, so here's to hoping. No clue whatsovere about Atwood's views.

Comment: I don't think "anthropomorphic" is the word you're looking for.

Comment: All that said, I'm not trying to change anyone's mind, or talk about climate change, just understand a big heap of code (awk, fortran, who knows what else).

Comment: @mmyers. Duh!!! Most definitely not!